# How to add a JPanel to an existing layout during runtime

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a `JPanel` in a swing desktop application containing components that were laid out using the GUI builder in NetBeans. In the generated source code, NetBeans uses the `GroupLayout` as Layout Manager. This `JPanel` is in a `JScrollPane`.

I have created another panel and manually handcoded the layout of the internal components of this second panel. During runtime, I want to add this second panel to the existing `GroupLayout` that was created by NetBeans at the click of a button.

See the Image below:

[image]

In the image above, there is a `JButton` labeled 'Enter' the red line below the button is where I want my new panel to appear when the button is clicked.

[image]

The above image illustrates what happens when I used the `GroupLayout.replace(Component existingComponent, Component newComponent)` method, but I don't want to use the replace method, I don't want to replace an existing panel, I just want to add the new panel to the existing layout. I can't seem to find any method in `GroupLayout` that does this. Please help.

Sorry the code for this question is too long to paste, I don't want to discourage answers, but I hope you understand what I am asking. Thanks.

Comment: it is possible first just put blank and panel and then replace with your new panel..

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just add an empty panel to the space below the red line. Expand it the size you want. Then when you click the button, just add that panel to the already existing empty panel, and `revalidate()` and `repaint()` that empty main panel.

Another solution is to us a `CardLayout` for that empty panel, and hand code an empty panel adding it to the first empty panel, then adding the panel you want to show to the main empty panel also. When the button is pressed, it switched the `CardLayout` to the panel you want show.

Solution 1.

```
private void jButtonXActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
    jPanelX.add(new MyOherPanel());
    jPanelX.revalidate();
    jPanelX.repaint();
}
```

Solution 2.

```
MyPanel myPanel = null;
public GUI(){
    intitComponents();
    jPanelX.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    jPanelX.add(new JPanel(), "emptyPanel");
    myPanel = new MyPanel();
    jPanelX.add(myPanel, "myPanel");
}

...
private void jButtonXActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)jPanelX.getLayout();
    layout.show(jPanelX, "myPanel");
}
```

Comment: No. I don't want an empty existing panel to be there.

Comment: I don't know GroupLayout at all, so I wouldn't be able to offer any solution as to adding your panel to the existing main Panel.

Comment: The problem is that the layout is already set. So you need to know how to use group layout to add a new panel to the main panel. But if you already place an empty panel to the layout, in design time, you can just add your new panel to it during runtime.

Comment: I don't want an existing panel to be there.

Comment: @Jevison7x I'm just curious, what is so wrong about having a blank panel?

Comment: What's the difference, if you're going to put a panel there anyway?

Comment: Because I will have to repeat this procedure numerous times dynamically, a blank panel will defeat this purpose.

Comment: Were you trying to add panel after panel, or for the new panel, another one should replace it?

Comment: I was trying to add panel after panel.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for replacing new JPanel to your existing JPanel.
`NewPanelClass` is the class where your new Five Textfield is placed and jpanel1 is current blank panel. so called CurrentPanel() on buttonclick event and you can get your panel in blank panel position as simple as that..In Group Layout.

```
private void CurrentPanel()
    {
        NewPanelClass mpanel = new NewPanelClass();
        this.getContentPane().remove(0);
        jPanel1.removeAll();
        javax.swing.GroupLayout firstPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(firstPanelLayout);
        firstPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                firstPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(firstPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(1, 1, 1).addComponent(mExploredDBView, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap(714, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        firstPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                firstPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(firstPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(1, 1, 1).addComponent(mExploredDBView, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE).addGap(1, 1, 1)));
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this.getContentPane());
    }
```

Thanks..

Comment: it is your panel code which has some jtextfield,Jbutton etc.. just create one panel from netbeans and replace that classname with newpanelclass..